# SphinxAPI SetFilter false

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx

I have sphinx installed for my search engine, and it works great, but now I'm trying to add a few extra features to the search using setFilter() which should allow me to do WHERE/AND clauses, but whenever I try a search, it returns no results when there should.

This is my MySQL Code : http://pastebin.com/gFrvKumW

This is my sphinx.conf : http://pastebin.com/XdppZ0MG

And my PHP code :

```
<?php
    require("sphinxapi.php");
    $cl = new SphinxClient();
    $host = "localhost";
    $port = 9312;
    $index = "library";
    $q = "livres";
    $limit = 20;
    $ranker = SPH_RANK_PROXIMITY_BM25;
    $mode = SPH_MATCH_ALL;
    $cl->SetServer($host, $port);
    $cl->SetConnectTimeout(0);
    $cl->SetMatchMode($mode);
    $cl->SetRankingMode($ranker);
    //$cl->SetFilter('author_id', array(1));
    $res = $cl->Query($q, $index);
    die(var_dump($res));
?>
```

if you add the commented line is not working anymore.
I do not understand why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to be able to use a field as a filter, you'll need to add it in the `sql_attr` on your [sphinx config file](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-0.9.9.html#conf-sql-attr-uint) so if you want to filter by autor id, you'll need to add (assuming that the author's id is an integer):

```
sql_query = SELECT `autors`.id, `books`.id, `books`.author_id, `books`.title, `books`.type, `authors`.name FROM `books`, `authors` WHERE `books`.author_id = `authors`.id
sql_attr_uint = autor_id
```

i hope this helps, Good Luck

Comment: Thanks of lot !

Is it possible to add a filter for text?